# Can connect with ts-node to service only by ip not by localhost

Tags: node.js, ts-node

I have a service that is bound to **0.0.0.0:1337**.

The service can be reached on my two network devices by **curl** at **http://localhost:1337** and **http://192.168.0.26:1337**.

However when I use the following ts code:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'http://localhost:1337',
};

const callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been received, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

and run it with **ts-node** I get a connection refused. When I use **host: 'http://192.168.0.26:1337'** then it works. This issue occured today after an ubuntu update.

Why can I do to solve the issue? I tried *node version* **16** and **18**. It's strange the it seems **node**-related because **curl** works.